# How do I export a query from PSQL to a CSV? Windows PSQL

Tags: sql, windows, csv, psql

I have the following code

```
\copy 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM person
    LEFT JOIN car ON car.id=person.car_id
) 
TO 'c:/Users/nick-/Downloads/results.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

and I'm getting back

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 6: TO 'c:/Users/nick-/Downloads/results.csv'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm following a tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4 timestamp 3:47:27) and am not seeing my error.

Comment: Probably the single quotes. Try using double quotes.

Comment: I tried and it had no effect.

Comment: a hint from the docs: filename: The absolute path name of the input or output file. Windows users might need to use an E'' string and double any backslashes used in the path name. Did you try the double backslash?

Comment: the syntax of ```copy``` comand may differ in different versions. what is your version?

Comment: I'm using the windows verson 13

Comment: I have used the \i function before doing using the following formatting and it worked `\i c:/Users/nick-/Downloads/person.sql`